# Rotativa [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

I am using Rotativa to generate Views as PDF and it **runs/works perfectly on my localhost**. However when deployed to either a shared host on GoDaddy or my Azure website instance I get the following error.

I attempted to grant permissions on .exe in the Rotativa folder with no luck, also tried running with Full Trust and still getting the error.

**ERROR / STACKTRACE**

> ```
> Access is denied
> ```
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is
>   denied
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo) +1789    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +6735098
>   Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.Convert(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String
>   switches, String html) +226
>   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.CallTheDriver(ControllerContext context) +26 
>   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.BuildPdf(ControllerContext context) +128
>   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +19 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +173    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +31    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9514928    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Print(Guid reportId)
{
    var report =  new ViewAsPdf("Index", new { id = reportId}) { FileName = "testReport.pdf" };
    return report;

}
```

**PERMISSIONS**
I tried to set permissions on the entire folder "Rotativa" with full control and now I get this...

> This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact
>   your system administrator
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: This program
>   is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system
>   administrator
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): This program is blocked by group policy.
>   For more information, contact your system administrator]
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo) +1789    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +6735098
>   Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.Convert(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String
>   switches, String html) +226
>   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.CallTheDriver(ControllerContext context) +26 
>   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.BuildPdf(ControllerContext context) +128
>   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +19 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +173    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +31    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9514928    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

**UPDATE JAN 13/2015**

I ended up switching to TuesPechkin which has been a far easier solution to work with. GoDaddy does support FullTrust as does Azure, however Azure has a known issue with running processes that call into the GDI which most wkhtmltopdf libraries do. TuesPechkin didn't work on Azure either so I never found a solution for an Azure website, but TuesPechkin worked perfect on GoDaddy hosting with the  set in my web.config.

Comment: how were you able to accomplish using TuesPechkin on GoDaddy?  Every attempt is resulting in a `Unable to load DLL 'wkhtmltox.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)` error.  Can you provide your code you used to define your converter? Did you use the nuget packages? Which package(s) did you use (32 or 64 bit)?  Thanks for your help. I'm really stuck!

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882601/tuespechkin-unable-to-load-dll-wkhtmltox-dll

Comment: I did, still confused... Everything works perfectly locally but fails on the GoDaddy server. I pulled the 32bit wmkhtmlox.dll out of the deployment source and published it to root/Resources; however, trying to find it using `new StaticDeployment(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Resources"))` is failing.  Did you use TempFolder or StaticDeployment for your deployment class?

Comment: Check out this thread, it has the code I used. https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin/issues/57 The latest version of Tues was fixed to include an embedded version of the dll. I used the TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.Win32 nuget package.

Comment: Yep, saw that too. `static IConverter converter = new ThreadSafeConverter(new RemotingToolset<PdfToolset>(new Win32EmbeddedDeployment(new TempFolderDeployment())));
  public static byte[] GetPDF(HtmlToPdfDocument document)
  {
   return converter.Convert(document);
  }` also fails

Comment: Email me, devfunkd[at]outlook[dot]com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both GoDaddy and azure websites don't allow for "Full trust" IIS hosting mode, and that's required in order to run the wkhtmltopdf process.
You should look for a hosting provider that gives full trust access if you want to use Rotativa.

Comment: They do allow it, I've confirmed it's not the issue.

Comment: Ok, so it must be some problem with access rights. "This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator". You should ask them if they allow executing exe processes.

Comment: I ended up switching to TuesPechkin which has been a far easier solution to work with. GoDaddy does support FullTrust as does Azure, however Azure has a known issue with running processes that call into the GDI which most wkhtmltopdf libraries do. TuesPechkin didn't work on Azure either so I never found a solution for an Azure website, but TuesPechkin worked perfect on GoDaddy hosting with the <trust level="Full" /> set in my web.config.

Answer (score 0):

For me I fixed the problem by allowing access to "Everyone" with full permission on the security pane of the file wkhtmltopdf.exe

I hope this helped someone if using a local testing machine or a virtual machine.

Note that you should also give the same allow permission to folder that will save the pdf output.