# How to instantiate TuesPechkin PDF library?

Tags: c#, pdf, iis-7, tuespechkin

What string is needed in TuesPechkin's StaticDeployment constructor? A temp folder?  A dll path?

My TuesPechkin PDF converter works fine on my localhost's IIS using:

```
private static readonly IConverter _pdfConverter = 
    new ThreadSafeConverter(
        new RemotingToolset<PdfToolset>(
            new Win64EmbeddedDeployment(
                 new TempFolderDeployment())));
```

But when running it on a Windows Server, IIS logs this error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'wkhtmltox.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found.

So I tried changing my constructor to this code (in case TuesPechkin was trying to unzip the dll to a path it didn't have write permissions for):

```
private static readonly IConverter _pdfConverter = 
    new ThreadSafeConverter(
        new RemotingToolset<PdfToolset>(
            new Win64EmbeddedDeployment(                    
                new StaticDeployment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\bin\")))));
```

Get the same error.
Both TuesPechkin.dll and TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.Win64.dll are in the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

This question has [already been answere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882601/tuespechkin-unable-to-load-dll-wkhtmltox-dll)d - install VC runtime: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784